# SQL Query Simplification - How to do in SQL Server what is currently done in the code?

Tags: sql, sql-server, while-loop

I am not very familiar with SQL queries, but I would like to move and combine multiple queries which I'm doing on the code level to the server to speed it up and to simplify it. Currently this takes several seconds even for only 5-10 items.

I have a view and a table, let's call them View1, Table1.

My first query:

```
SELECT UnitSerialNumber
FROM Table1
WHERE OrderID = 1234
    AND IsActive = 1
ORDER BY SerialNumberDate, IsPrinted
```

This returns a list (every item is a unique `UnitSerialNumber`), which I'm looping through...

`BEGINNING OF LOOP`

```
SELECT ResultId
FROM View1
WHERE Data = UnitSerialNumber
    AND ItemId = 338
    AND StatusId = 2
```

This returns a single value (`ResultId`) which I'm using in a query...

```
SELECT Data
FROM View1
WHERE ID = ResultId
    AND (ItemId = 311 OR ItemId = 313)
    AND StatusId = 2
ORDER BY ItemId
```

(I know this table structure is crap, but I'm not in the position to do anything with it, this is how the data stored.) So this returns with an object with 2 values.

`END OF LOOP`

Comment: How does this return two values?  I only see one.  Also, your logic would be much easier to follow if you had sample data and desired results.

Comment: 5-10 items? Okay, but which part is actually a parameter for the items?

Comment: Can you do this: select t1.UnitSerialNumber ,v1.ResultId ,v2.Data 
from Table1 t1
inner join View1 v1
on t1.UnitSerialNumber = v1.Data
inner join View1 v2
on v2.ID = v1.ResultId 
where t1.OrderID=1234 
AND t1.IsActive=1
AND v1.ItemId=338 
AND v1.StatusId=2
AND v2.ItemIdin (311,313)
AND v2.StatusId=2
order by v2.itemid

Comment: Anytime you think about looping through records you are going to hav ea slow process. You need to stop thinking in terms of looping. 99+% of the time looping is bad. Start thinking terms of sets and joins instead.

Comment: @Jayesh, that returned with no result :/

Comment: @Steven are there any special characters/extra spaces in the data of any join columns that we should know of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have given a try with subqueries, this is working for me. Thanks everyone for trying to help!

```
SELECT View1.Data, View1.ItemId, z.SerialNumberDate, z.IsPrinted
    FROM View1
    JOIN
    (
            SELECT View1.Id, x.SerialNumberDate, x.IsPrinted
            FROM View1
            JOIN
            (
                    SELECT UnitSerialNumber, SerialNumberDate, IsPrinted
                    FROM Table1
                    WHERE OrderID = 613 AND IsActive = 1
            )
            AS x ON View1.Data = x.UnitSerialNumber
    )
    AS z ON View1.DataCardId = z.Id
    WHERE View1.ItemId = 313 AND z.IsPrinted IS NULL
    ORDER BY z.IsPrinted,z.SerialNumberDate
```

Answer (score 0):

CTEs are a simple way to combine such queries:

```
with q1 as (
      SELECT UnitSerialNumber, SerialNumberDate, IsPrinted
      FROM Table1
      WHERE OrderID = 1234 AND IsActive = 1 
     ),
     q2 as (
      SELECT ResultId, SerialNumberDate, IsPrinted
      FROM View1
      WHERE ItemId = 338 AND StatusId = 2 AND
            Data in (SELECT UnitSerialNumber FROM q1)
    )
SELECT q2.ResultId, v.Data
FROM q2 JOIN
     View1 v
     ON v.ID = q2.ResultId 
WHERE v.itemId IN (311, 313) AND v.StatusId = 2
ORDER BY a2.SerialNumberDate, q2.IsPrinted, v.ItemId;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, unfortunately this returns with no result.

Comment: @Steven  . . . That seems odd.  Can you determine if the two CTEs return rows.

Comment: Q1 is fine on its own. Q2 doesn't have SerialNumberDate and IsPrinted, and if I replace to Data ='xxxx' it works fine as well. I disabled the order by part, and run the whole, and it returns with no result :/

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    v1.Data
FROM
    View1 v1
JOIN
    View1 v2
        ON v1.ID = v2.ResultId
JOIN
    Table1 t
        ON v2.Data = t.UnitSerialNumber
WHERE
    (v1.ItemId = 311 OR v1.ItemId = 313)
    AND v1.StatusId = 2
    AND v2.ItemId = 338
    AND v2.StatusId = 2
    AND t.OrderID = 1234
    AND t.IsActive = 1
ORDER BY
    v1.ItemId;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, unfortunately this returns with no result.